# NodeJS How to make a get request with two parameteres in the query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

i'm writing a get methode in node js and i have an error when i want get the data base it show me an error that the query return null despite the document exist

```
router.get('/getmodele',(req,res,next)=>{
  let aa=req.query.imei;
  console.log(aa);
  Post.findOne( {imei: {
    'imei.name':req.query.imei,'imei.modele':req.query.modele
  },
  test: {
    $exists: false
  }})
  .
  then((posts) => {
```

my request take at time two parameteres
i need some helps and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dot notation when querying.

```
 Post.findOne( {'imei.name':req.query.imei,'imei.modele':req.query.modele})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be like this:

```js
{
  imei: {
    name: req.query.imei,
    modele: req.query.modele
  } 
}
```

Comment: the same probleme